# What does Windows MongoDB Compass show no collection infos, but Ubuntu MongoDB Compass does?

Tags: mongodb, windows, ubuntu, mongodb-compass

I have the same database and collection in MongoDB on Ubuntu and Windows.

In my Compass on Ubuntu, it shows the information about the collection:

[image]

However, my Compass on Windows shows no information about the collection:

[image]

Although when I click on the collection in Windows, it shows that the collection indeed has 91 documents, just as on Ubuntu:

[image]

**Why doesn't MongoDB Compass for Windows show information about collections and how can I force it to do this?**

## ADDENDUM

I installed MongoDB Compass on a Windows 10 virtual machine and it displays the collection information correctly. So perhaps this issue is not related to Windows but more a question why would MongoDB Compass not display information about collections in general?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem myself.

For anyone who has this issue, it turned out that I had an older version of MongoDB installed which was starting instead of the one that apparently installed with Mongo.

I deinstalled all Mongo Compass instances, reinstalled Mongo Compass from https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass and it works now.